# O que é REST e RESTful?

Tags: api, rest, http, arquitetura-de-software, restful

Sempre ouço falar de `REST` e `RESTful`, mas não sei diferenciar um do outro nem para que servem.

Me pareceu algo com padrão de arquitetura de aplicação estilo Common.js.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Só faz sentido saber o que é REST, já que RESTful é apenas a capacidade de fazer REST, ou seja, é uma questão gramatical.

A Representational State Transfer (REST), em português Transferência de Estado Representacional, é uma abstração da arquitetura da World Wide Web, mais precisamente, é um estilo arquitetural que consiste de um conjunto coordenado de restrições arquiteturais aplicadas a componentes, conectores e elementos de dados dentro de um sistema de hipermídia distribuído.

O REST ignora os detalhes da implementação de componente e a sintaxe de protocolo com o objetivo de: focar nos papéis dos componentes, nas restrições sobre sua interação com outros componentes e na sua interpretação de elementos de dados significantes.

Ele foi definido oficialmente pela [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).

Fonte: [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer))

Ele é frequentemente aplicado à *web services*, fornecendo APIs para acesso a um serviço qualquer na web. Ele usa integralmente as mensagens HTTP para se comunicar através do que já é definido no protocolo, sem precisar "inventar" novos protocolos específicos para aquela aplicação.

Você trabalha essencialmente com componentes, conectores e dados.

- Ele usa o protocolo HTTP (verbos, *accept headers*, códigos de estado HTTP, *Content-Type*) de forma explícita e representativa para se comunicar. URIs são usados para expor a estrutura do serviço. Utiliza uma notação comum para transferência de dados como XML ou JSON.
- Não possui estado entre essas comunicações, ou seja, cada comunicação é independente e uniforme (padronizada), precisando passar toda informação necessária.
- Ele deve facilitar o cache de conteúdo no cliente.
- Deve ter clara definição do que faz parte do cliente e do servidor. O cliente não precisa saber como o servidor armazena dados, por exemplo. Assim cada implementação não depende da outra e se torna mais escalável.
- Permite o uso em camadas também facilitando a escalabilidade, confiabilidade e segurança.
- Frequentemente é criado com alguma forma de extensibilidade.

Falhando em um dos cinco primeiros itens, a arquitetura não pode ser classificada formalmente como RESTful. Mas nem todo mundo se apega ao formalismo.

Exemplo:

```
http://example.com/apagar/produto/1234
```

Significa que você está pedindo para apagar o produto de ID 1234.

Há quem diga que isto está errado. Já que a ênfase é em cima dos recursos, e não das operações, deveria usar assim:

```
http://example.com/produto/1234 (utilizando o verbo/método DELETE)
```

Convenhamos que isto pode servir para CRUD, mas existem tantas variações do que precisa ser feito que não é possível representar tudo só com os verbos HTTP. Ok, é possível fazer tudo parecer CRUD, mas talvez exija informações adicionais em nome do formalismo.

Tudo isto é pensado para proporcionar melhor performance, escalabilidade, simplicidade, flexibilidade, visibilidade, portabilidade e confiabilidade.

Cada um define como quiser sua API, ao contrário de SOAP onde tudo é definido oficialmente.

[Fonte canônica na dissertação do Dr. Roy Fielding](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: bigown há alguma fonte no site para SOAP? Se houver era interessante linkar aqui no fim do seu texto.

Comment: @JorgeB. quando eu não sei se é boa eu prefiro não *linkar*, porque meio que eu estaria abonando aquilo.

Comment: @bigown assumi que fosse uma resposta sua ;)

Comment: Como assim utilizando o verbo DELETE? `http://example.com/produto/1234 (utilizando o verbo DELETE)` Onde está o uso dele?

Comment: Tem que mandar o comando para o servidor.

Comment: @DiegoSouza, o verbo (ou método) HTTP não se encontra na URL, mas sim no como é feita a chamada ao servidor. Essa [seção de artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) fornece os verbos mais comuns e sua semântica. Só para ratificar e você não se perde na nomenclatura, note que na Wikipedia tem uma preferência maior a chamar de _métodos HTTP_ no lugar de _verbos_

Answer (score 79):

## REST

Segundo [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST):

> É pensada como uma **imagem do design** da aplicação se comportará.

Ou seja, seria algo como, dependendo maneira que se consome um mesmo recurso - recurso esse que pode ser identificado visualmente inclusive - seu comportamento irá mudar.

Vamos ilustrar para facilitar:

#### Sobre Requisições HTTP

Toda as vezes que acessamos algo via *browser* (navegador), várias **requisicões** são disparadas. Quando acessa uma página qualquer, uma requisição pelo conteúdo dessa página é criado. Quando esse conteúdo retornar, o *browser* monta (*renderiza*) a página, mas essa página requer outros recursos como imagens, fontes, folhas de estilo (*css*). Para cada recurso, o navegador irá fazer uma nova requisição.

Essas requisições são compostas, principalmente, de três informações:

- URL: Endereço que irá receber a requisição;
- Verbo/Método: Comando que se deseja que seja feito;
- Corpo: Informações que enviamos, como dados de um formulário, por exemplo.

Quantos aos Verbos, existem 4 que são os mais utilizados:

- GET: Usado para trazer informações
- POST: Para criar/adicionar informações
- PUT: Para atulizar informações
- DELETE: Para excluir informações

#### Serviço RESTful

São serviços que possuem comportamento REST. Ou seja, usando o mesmo design, seu comportamento irá mudar de acordo com a maneira que é consumido

Por exemplo, temos a URL (*endpoint*) abaixo:

#### `http://www.contoso.com/alunos`

Se queremos trazer a lista de alunos, basta realizamos uma requisição `GET`:

```
Request:
[GET] http://www.contoso.com/alunos
Body: empty
```

A resposta será algo como:

```
Response:
HTTP Code 200 OK
[
    { id: 1, nome: "Thiago Lunardi" },
    { id: 2, nome: "Joe Satriani"}
]
```

Mas, se eu quiser adicionar um novo aluno, uso o mesmo design, mas consumindo de outra forma, com requisição `POST`:

```
Request:
[POST] http://www.contoso.com/alunos
Body: { "nome: "Slash" }

HTTP Code 201 Created
{ id: 3, nome: "Slash" }
```

Continuando, para saber mais detalhes sobre um aluno:

```
Request:
[GET] http://www.contoso.com/alunos/1
Body: empty

Response:
HTTP Code 200 OK
{ 
    id: 1, 
    nome: "Thiago Lunardi",
    github: "https://github.com/ThiagoLunardi",
    website: "http://thiagolunardi.net",
    blog: "https://medium.com/@thiagolunardi",
}
```

Para atualizar informações de um ano, da mesma forma, usamos o mesmo design, e apenas mudamos a forma de consumir o recurso, e ele terá um comportamento diferente:

```
Request:
[PUT] http://www.contoso.com/alunos/1
Body: { "twitter": "@thiagolunardi13" }

Response:
HTTP Code 200 OK
{ 
    id: 1, 
    nome: "Thiago Lunardi",
    github: "https://github.com/ThiagoLunardi",
    website: "http://thiagolunardi.net",
    blog: "https://medium.com/@thiagolunardi",
    twitter: "@thiagolunardi13"
}
```

Para excluir:

```
Request:
[DELETE] http://www.contoso.com/alunos/1
Body: empty

Response:
HTTP Code 204 No Content
```

Comment: Rapaz, foi a melhor explicação do conceito `Restful` que já li, e nem estava procurando por isso, estava pesquisando se o termo correto é `Restful` ou `Restfull`, e cai aqui. +1

Answer (score 17):

O termo *REST* [significa](https://blog.ndepend.com/rest-vs-restful/) **Re**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer.

Nada mais é que um padrão de arquitetura para criar serviços e disponibilizá-los na Web. Um serviço *RESTful* é simplesmente aquele que realiza a implementação deste padrão.

Ou seja, não há diferenças.

O termo REST surgiu com o Roy Fielding em uma [dissertação](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) que escreveu em 2000. Nesta dissertação ele classificava um serviço REST com algumas características. As principais, entendo eu, seriam:

- **Cliente-servidor**: de um lado temos o servidor trabalhando com os dados e do outro o cliente fazendo suas interações. Esta separação de responsabilidades deve ser a mais clara possível.
- **Sem estado** (*stateless*): as requisições do cliente para o servidor deve conter todas as informações. O servidor não deve manter o estado do cliente (sessão) do seu lado.
- **Cacheável**: as respostas do servidor devem determinas se aquela informação pode entrar ou não em um cache. Assim o cliente pode confiar se aquela resposta pode ser usada novamente em uma requisição equivalente.
- **Interface uniforme**: este item tem relação com o uso correto dos verbos HTTP GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc e de uma separação clara dos recursos e de seus níveis.

Ou seja, um serviço REST não é aquele que simplesmente manda um Json de um lado para o outro. Existem certas regras definidas para que possa ser mais fácil de ser usada, mais confiável e com melhor performance.

Um exemplo que deixa isto mais claro é quando comparamos dois serviços http onde um é **baseado** em REST e o outro não é. Vamos começar com um exemplo de API que gerencia pedidos.

## API de pedido: RPC com HTTP vs REST

RPC significa *Remote Procedure Call*. É uma definição genérica que, basicamente, está relacionada a requisições remotas e síncronas (independente do protocolo). Uma simples chamada HTTP sem observar qualquer padrão já pode ser considerada uma chamada RPC.

Sendo assim, a melhor maneira que vejo de explicar o que está próximo do REST **é mostrar um exemplo que está bem distante do REST**.

### RPC com HTTP

Vamos imaginar que queremos criar um novo pedido usando `POST` em uma API RPC:

```
POST /pedidos

{
    "NovoPedido": {
          "nome": "Nome do Pedido",
          "valor": "9.99",
          "numero": "1001"
      }
}
```

E para buscar o pedido pelo seu identificador:

```
POST /pedidos

{
    "BuscarPedido": {
          "numero": "1001"
      }
}
```

E, por fim, remover o pedido ficaria:

```
POST /pedidos

{
    "RemoverPedido": {
          "numero": "1001"
      }
}
```

Bem, isso não é REST. Simplesmente estamos chamando a mesma função com parâmetros diferentes. Não está claro na API que temos diferentes formas de alterar o estado do recurso "pedido".

Vamos ver como ficaria o mesmo exemplo baseando-se no REST.

### REST (ou quase isto...)

Em uma API baseada em REST teríamos algo assim para criar pedido:

```
POST /pedidos

{
  "nome": "Nome do Pedido",
  "valor": "9.99",
  "numero": "1001"
}
```

Buscar o pedido pelo id nem precisaria de um *body* na requisição, só usaríamos as informações presente na própria URL, passando o identificador do pedido:

```
GET /pedidos/1001
```

E remover o pedido seria parecido com o `GET`:

```
DELETE /pedidos/1001
```

E cada um dos serviços acima também retornaria o status HTTP correspondente. No caso do `POST` seria um `201 CREATED` (que significa "sucesso, recurso foi criado"). No caso do GET seria um `200 OK` ("sucesso"). No caso do `DELETE` seria um `204 NO CONTENT` ("sucesso, sem conteúdo para retornar como resposta").

Porém, os exemplos acima ainda **não podem ser considerados de uma API RESTful**. Perceba que em alguns momentos eu usei a palavra "baseada" ou "quase" para classificar "RESTibilidade" da API do exemplo anterior.

## E por qual motivo a API acima é "baseada" em REST e não RESTFul?

A maioria dos desenvolvedores acredita que uma API RESTFul pára nos exemplos acima, mas para uma API realmente ser considerada RESTFul ela deveria também aplicar o [HATEOAS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49492/por-que-hateoas-%C3%A9-importante) [de acordo com o próprio Roy](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven):

> if the engine of application state (and hence the API) is not being
> driven by hypertext, then it cannot be RESTful and cannot be a REST
> API. Period.

Creio que esta polêmica de definir o que é uma API REST ou não acabou gerando [os níveis de maturidade](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) de uma API Rest, dada a dificuldade (ou até, pouca necessidade) de aplicar o HATEOAS nas APIs. Estes níveis de maturidade podem auxiliar os desenvolvedores a entenderem que ponto suas APIs estão no momento e até onde podemos chegar dada as necessidades da API a ser desenvolvida.