# O suporte a usuários que não usam Javascript está acabando?

Tags: javascript, acessibilidade

Sim, óbvio que é importante, porém eu vejo muitos sites que simplesmente *não* funcionam se o JavaScript estiver desligado. É mais por uma questão de curiosidade, mas hoje em dia é quase obrigatório usar JavaScript em um site grande, então o hábito do "suporte aos usuários que não tem" acaba? Exemplos de sites que não funcionam com o JavaSript desligado:

- http://www.tecmundo.com.br/
- http://unfold.no/
- http://www.shibui.me/web/scroll/index.html
- http://www.supremo.tv/

Lógico que tudo depende do tipo de site que está a ser desenvolvido, mas me refiro aos sites novos que usam vários efeitos bonitos como Parallax, bibliotecas como o Bootstrap e o jQuery, etc. Em especial sites One Page, que usam e abusam do JavaScript, tendo resultados fantásticos.
Então no desenvolvimento desses sites, esse quesito é deixado de lado?

Comment: Eu tenho uma opinião que muita gente não vai gostar, mas eu acho que ao menos 70% dos sites que não funcionam sem JS são incompetência do programador (hoje muitos dos sites que eu tenho visto são feitos por equipes de moleques, e falo isso com a maior tranquilidade, doa a quem doer). _Graceful degradation_ e principalmente _Progressive enhancement_ são dois conceitos que já são postos em prática por uma série de bons desenvolvedores, e garantem o acesso à informação por uma gama muito maior de dispositivos. Sites de serviços públicos como o registro.br, por exemplo, deveriam ter isso em mente.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/101

Comment: Adendo: para alguns do SOpt deve ser difícil acreditar nisso, mas existem pessoas que não vivem centradas no PC, ou nem tem condições de (ou simplesmente não deveriam precisar) trocar o PC velho (não precisa ser tão velho, um Athlon de 3Ghz já tem dificuldades por não ter SSE) e não tem como usar browsers novos. Tudo bem que algum tonto pode dizer que "esses pobres que não vão comprar o meu produto, então não tou nem aí", mas tenhamos bom senso. Outros já não conseguem fazer nada que não tenha pronto no framework da moda que dependem de JS, e por isso a coisa está indo pra esse rumo.

Comment: Não sabia sobre os conceitos do _Graceful degradation_ e _Progressive enhancement_, com certeza serão coisas que lembrarei na hora de fazer o layout um site. Obrigado pela opinião, andei dando uma pesquisada e descobri uma tag chamada `<noscript>` que talvez você já conheça. Tentarei dar ao máximo suporte a todos os usuários, assim é menos um programador incompetente :]

Comment: Tem um site muito interessante, que mostra que temos _sim_ que nos preocupar primeiro com o conteúdo, depois com as "firulas", que não agregam muito valor ao usuário (sim, CSS e JavaScript agregam valor, mas o conteúdo sempre ganha): http://sighjavascript.tumblr.com/.

Comment: @Bacco tudo bom? Eu sou sócio de uma pequena empresa, e vou dar uma visão um pouco diferente. Eu adoro graceful degradation. Hell, eu quero que os meus sites funcionem no meu nintendo 2ds. Mas, entretanto, especialmente aqui no brasil, isso é caro. Okay, tudo aqui é caro. Mas qualquer componente a  mais que a gente utilize no site, requer um pouco mais de investimento. E se eu quero pagar alguém o valor justo (ou seja, pagar meu UX um valor realmente de UX, e não de um sobrinho/estágiario por 34h de freela..) Não dá. A gente tem que tirar algumas coisas. Suporte é uma delas...

Comment: @Malavos penso que estamos falando de coisas diferentes (posso não ter entendido direito, claro). Falei de quem programa os componentes, mas o cenário que você descreveu me parece mais de reuso de frameworks. Com certeza se a pessoa vai usar o que tem pronto no mercado, refazer sai caro. Mas se é você (ou sua equipe) que programa, não vejo razão pra não fazer algo mais completo desde o começo, pq dá trabalho uma vez, mas você reaproveita (se fizer modular, claro). Mas eu reconheço que tenha mais de um tipo de público alvo, e é claro que cada um tem que focar no que funciona para si.

Comment: @Malavos tentando simplificar: na minha experiência, muito pode ser feito sem trabalho adicional, bastando a pessoa ter um mínimo de preocupação a mais. Casos em que precisa realmente fazer algo complexo para atender devices antigos eu diria que é exceção. Sei que se quiser fazer tudo compativel com tudo, é tarefa interminável, mas tem um "meio termo" que o pessoal não atinge por excesso de comodidade. Por exemplo, por um google maps no site sem JS fica precário, mas isso não significa que você não possa deixar o resto do site navegável com ancoras em vez de JS (mero exemplo);

Comment: @Malavos qq hora dessas dê um pulinho no [chat da rede](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/), ai dá pra vc contar melhor essas experiências e de repente elaborarmos melhor o assunto

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript, com o passar dos anos, tornou-se muito procurado, tendo dado origem a todo um universo de frameworks com as quais a Internet dos dias de hoje parece não sobreviver.

[Brendan Eich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich) foi o criador da linguagem JavaScript em 1995, mais tarde o fundador do universo Mozilla, que à umas versões atrás, no seu produto Firefox versão 23 [removeu a opção para desligar o JavaScript](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994809#answer-556927).

Atendendo que o pessoal da Mozilla é uma referencia no que respeita à Internet, uso e produtividade sob a mesma, e atendendo ao fato de terem removido a opção para desligar o JavaScript, eu diria que sim, que o suporte a pessoal (usuários) sem JavaScript vai acabar!

### JavaScript, uma opção ?

A web não anda sem HTML, mas todo e qualquer outro conteúdo multimédia ou linguagem no lado do cliente foi sempre facultativa: JavaScript, CSS, Imagens, Video, etc.

A questão é que nos dias de hoje, com a exigência do publico alvo a aumentar constantemente, com toda a procura de dinamismo e operações em tempo real, a constante tentativa de "abolir" o chato do page-refresh, torna-se difícil para qualquer profissional da área satisfazer o mercado atual sem JavaScript.

Já nem o CSS 2.1 serve para a maior parte dos trabalhos, vai-se lá imaginar uma página sem CSS!

O mesmo se passa com o JavaScript:

- Validações de dados em tempo real;
- Efeitos visuais;
- Temporizadores;
- Conteúdo dinâmico;
- Camadas adicionais de proteção em aplicações;

E muitas outra aplicações práticas que tornam o JavaScript indispensável nos dias modernos, fazem com que o mesmo já não seja uma opção mas sim uma necessidade.

Isto é um fato adquirido sob o qual os fornecedores de navegadores trabalham para melhorar e tendem, como a Mozilla, a evoluir ao invés de estagnarem.

### JavaScript, tem futuro ?

Quem se recorda de ter trabalho em Flash sabe que a mudança é inevitável e que de hoje para amanhã existe algo novo, melhorado que vem substituir aquilo a que estamos habituados.

Flash foi uma moda, durante anos os sites eram desenvolvidos em flash, o próprio Flash cresceu, foi melhorado e tornou-se a ferramenta indispensável. Hoje, HTML5 faz o que o Flash fazia, de forma mais simples, mais eficaz e com menos problemas de compatibilidade e sem requerer plugins.

O JavaScript vai chegar à fase em que o Flash se encontra hoje, morto na água! Para já, é uma linguagem cheia de vida e futuro, mas com HTML5 e CSS3, muita da necessidade de JavaScript desapareceu, a dada altura também ele irá desaparecer.

Ex.:

Verificar se determinado campo num formulário está vazio:

```
<form name="meuFormulario" method="post">
  Pergunta: <input name="question" />
  <br />
  <input onclick="return IsEmpty();" type="submit" value="Adicionar Pergunta" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['meuFormulario'].question.value == "")
  {
    alert("vazio");
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}
```

HTML5

Basta adicionar o atributo `required` ao nosso campo, e o navegador trata do resto!

### [Progressive Enhancement](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30238/223)

A técnica assenta num principio simples, criar algo sólido e funcional, indo-se depois aplicar toda uma camada de funcionalidades extra que podem ou não ser utilizadas, se o suporte necessário para as mesmas se encontra disponível.

Nada do paragrafo em cima se verifica na maioria dos sites ou plataformas online atualmente. Tudo o que se procura é fazer bem, rápido e moderno porque daqui a meio ano é para apagar e fazer algo novo!

- Navegadores avançam de versão em versão tão rápido que quando vou fazer uma atualização já vou 3 ou 4 versões atrás;
- As tecnologias mudam de tal forma que a melhor solução que temos hoje, daqui a um mês é um "crime" utilizar.
- Faço um trabalho hoje, daqui a meio ano o cliente quer algo novo, totalmente diferente.

Mas o que é que é mais importante: Avançar ou perder um tempo infinito a garantir que uma pequena minoria que insiste em não avançar consiga ver o que os outros que avançaram estão a ver?

ou seja

Trabalhar com tecnologia atual, entre a qual JavaScript ou continuar a perder um tempo infinito para garântir que quem usa Internet Explorer 7 com JavaScript desligado vai poder utilizar o SOpt ?

#### Eu diria que sim, que o suporte a pessoal (usuários) sem JavaScript vai acabar!

Answer (score 4):

Tudo depende da **exigência** de tais usuários: se houver pressão para que os sites funcionem sem JavaScript, ainda existirão sites que funcionem sem JavaScript. Se não houver, não existirão...

Eu diria que a grande maioria das pessoas não dá a mínima pra isso (ou sequer sabem que isso existe!). Mas há um grupo expressivo que se importa - sejam "fanáticos" por software livre que [não querem código não-livre executando em sua máquina](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.html), sejam "paranóicos" por segurança que não querem código arbitrário executando em sua máquina, sejam pessoas comuns de saco cheio de tanta propaganda que preferem [habilitar seletivamente](https://noscript.net/) o JavaScript mas mantê-lo desligado por padrão (categoria na qual eu me incluo<sup>1</sup>).

Pessoas físicas e empresas privadas têm total liberdade para ignorar esses grupos - em geral pequenos demais para fazer um diferença significativa em seus bolsos. Já sites oficiais do governo, por exemplo, podem ser obrigados por lei a manter certos serviços acessíveis, caso sofram pressão suficiente para isso. É o mesmo caso dos sites que só funcionavam no IE ou dos programas que só funcionavam no Windows - o pessoal reclamou tanto que hoje a situação já é bastante diferente (o programa pra fazer declaração de Imposto de Renda, por exemplo, é *cross-platform*; e muitos bancos têm "modulos de segurança" específicos pro IE - via ActiveX - e pro resto - via Java). Se pressão semelhante existir para que certos sites funcionem sem JavaScript, não restará alternativa a não ser fazer dessa forma<sup>2</sup>.

Mas para a grande maioria das aplicações, eu concordo com [os argumentos do Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56860/215) - se espera muito mais de um site hoje em dia do que simplesmente ler informação estática e ocasionalmente postar alguma coisa. De modo que o uso de JavaScript se tornará mais e mais pervasivo. A menos é claro que alguém invente uma *engine* mais versátil que um *browser* - talvez até tornando os *browsers* obsoletos (difícil mas possível - o protocolo HTTP foi pensado de forma que os clientes - ou *User Agents* - [evoluíssem de forma independente dos servidores, e vice-versa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49492/215)). Que permita fazer 95% do que os sites atuais fazem, porém de uma forma puramente declarativa, sem precisar de código [executável] arbitrário. Difícil de imaginar hoje em dia, mas todas as tecnologias **disruptivas** começam assim... ;)

---

<sub>1. Sério! Experimente navegar 1 mês com NoScript ligado e depois voltar ao que era antes. Você não aguenta... A Internet fica *literalmente* mais bonita com o NoScript!</sub>

<sub>2. E existem [razões mais importantes que evitar anúncios](http://venturebeat.com/2014/03/10/why-edward-snowden-gave-a-shoutout-to-the-noscript-add-on-for-firefox/) para se desabilitar JavaScript, *especialmente* em sites vindos do(s) governo(s)...</sub>