# Esconder codigo HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

É o seguinte, se puderem, acessem um website qualquer desativem o javascript e façam <kbd>F5</kbd> para atualizar.
Irão ver que o conteúdo do site desapareceu, contudo se vocês carregarem por exemplo <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, vão ver que o HTML continua lá todo na mesma.

O que eu gostava de saber é como é que eu escondo certo HTML quando o javascript estiver desativado :)

Eu sei que existe algo assim parecido mas com o script do adblock, que ele esconde HTML enquanto nós tivermos o adblock ativo.

Mas eu queria mas é algo parecido ou igual, mas apenas com para com o javascript desligado :)

Comment: Acho que se você ocultasse por padrão o seu body com `CSS` usando `body { display: none; }` e utiliza-se o JS para exibir iria funcionar.

Comment: Você pode usar a tag `<noscript>` para mostrar o conteúdo quando não houver javascript ativado.

Comment: Você quer esconder a página renderizada ou o código fonte?

Comment: Richard Dias, talvez funcione :) depois exprimento :P

Guilherme Nascimento, quero esconder o codigo fonte.

Comment: @BabyStar então nenhum dos exemplos citados irá funcionar, na verdade não é possivel esconder o código, o que é possível fazer é dificultar a leitura do mesmo e mesmo com JavaScript habilitado e você bloqueado o contextmenu e Ctrl+U ainda sim é fácil ver o código-fonte.

Comment: Eu acho que vou fazer como tenho por exemplo da placa de status como está la em cima no canto superior direito :)
Se eu desabilitar o javascript vc só ve a placa fazendo loading, e mesmo que vc vá ao codigo fonte, vc não verá o codigo do conteudo, apenas verá a tag <img> do loading :P

Deverá ser esta a melhor maneira xD

Comment: vc deve aplicar a tag `<noscript>` para exitar que um determinado trecho de código não apareça quando o javascript estiver desativado. O problema está no modo como fez a pergunta, tal como o título que dão a entender que deseja ocultar o código.. O que parece que vc quer  é impedir a renderização ou execução de trechos específicos de código.

Answer (score 2):

1. Usar `<iframe/>`. O browser precisa do HTML gerado para mostrar o seu site.
2. Você não pode esconder o código HTML completamente.
3. Não instigue o usuário a buscar mais formas de achar o seu código.
4. Qualquer solução no lado cliente é perda de tempo (e se o usuário se desabilitar o JS?).
5. **Pra quê você precisa disso?**

Answer (score 1):

voce pode carregar a página com display:none e quando a página for carregada, um script javascript remover esse display none, entao se não carregar js, o código não será exibido.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode carregar o conteúdo da página dinamicamente com AJAX, usando o jQuery por exemplo. Dessa forma, se o JavaScript estiver desativado no navegador, o conteúdo não será carregado.

O jQuery tem um método chamado **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** que permite carregar o corpo da resposta no elemento.

Eu fiz um fiddle para exemplificar: *https://jsfiddle.net/L8u37ge7/*

```
$("#content").load("/echo/html/", {"html": "<h1>Teste</h1><p>Texto Teste</p>"});
```

O método load recebe como parâmetro uma URL. Nesse caso eu utilizei o serviço do JsFiddle para criar uma requisição ajax.

De forma mais genérica:

```
$(elemento).load(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível esconder o código fonte do usuário, uma vez que o navegador já o tenha carregado. O *máximo* que pode ser feito é uma condição por PHP, assim o código não é mostrado, mas como o PHP é uma linguagem *server-side*, ele não pode detectar o JavaScript no navegador.

E outra, o elemento `<noscript>` serve para mostrar conteúdo quando o JavaScript está desabilitado, porém se acessarmos o código fonte, todo o HTML ainda estará lá. Geralmente o que acontece nesse site que você passou é que os elementos só são mostrados com o JavaScript , veja o que tem na tag `body` do site:

```
<body id="bg" onload="inicializar()">
```

Ou seja, quando o site carregar será rodada a função `inicializar()` que mostra o conteúdo do site, contudo, todo o HTML ainda está lá, somente oculto visualmente.

Gostaria de aproveitar para lhe avisar que essa prática deve ser evitada, afinal, não são todos os usuário que habilitam o JavaScript, tornando a experiência de acessar seu site um desastre total. Dê uma lida: [O suporte a usuários que não usam Javascript está acabando?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56846/o-suporte-a-usu%C3%A1rios-que-n%C3%A3o-usam-javascript-est%C3%A1-acabando)

Comment: Não não, vc está errado xD 
O onload="inicializar()" serve apenas para mudar o fundo do site em tempo real xD
Não tem nada a ver com o carregamento do site :P
Contudo agradeço sempre as ajudas e comentarios feitos :)

Comment: a intenção não é esconder o código fonte.. é não permitir que certas partes não apareçam quandop desativar o javascript... para isso usa-se a tag `<noscript>`

Answer (score 0):

Esqueça os pessimista ou preguiços que dizem não ser possivel, é perfeitamente possivel e viavel!

Eu faço assim, acredito ser o jeito mais pratico e semântico, basta você colocar isso no seu `<head>`, dessa forma:

```
<noscript><style>.notjs{display:none:!important;}</style></noscript>
```

No elemento que você quer esconder, inclua a classe `notjs`, dessa forma:

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="notjs">
```

Se você estiver usando select2, jquery ou algo que quebre o seu design como é o meu caso, utilize bootstrap, coloque a versão css abaixo da versão javascript, dessa forma:

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="notjs">
<noscript><input type="text" name="search" class="form-control"></noscript>
```

Ele irá substituir a input automaticamente, escondendo uma e mostrando a outra, quando o javascript estiver ativado você poderá usar jquery ou outra biblioteca js para retirar a versão css que irá funcionar sem JS, você vai encontrar no google como excluir elementos manipulando o DOM, isso é tranquilo. Sempre lembrando que este código não tem efeito na view-source, pois ali ele não carrega código nenhum, é apenas um texto, mais terá efeito na sua pagina ao vivo e você não verá o código no DOM(console) e é suficiente para este tipo de situação.

Agora, se mesmo assim você acredita que o usuário não deve ver aquela pagina sem javascript, então temos 2 opções;

!) tiramos o usuário da pagina problemática e levamos ele para uma que funcione apenas com o básico (html e css).

2. cobrimos a pagina com um fundo preto e colocamos um aviso para informar que o javascript é necessário.

- No primeiro caso podemos fazer assim:

Se o javascript estiver desativado ele vai redirecionar o usuário imediatamente para outra pagina, certamente ele ficará muito nervoso por não fazer o que estava pretendendo, geralmente usar o botão bloqueado do mouse ou copiar alguma coisa e dificilmente ele conseguirá, principalmente se você colocar este código logo abaixo do `<head>`. O navegador vai entender o recado e vai fazer o que você pede, no máximo a pessoa ficará tentando impedir o carregamento total, a mesma técnica usada para acessar a folha, estadão, o globo e outros, mais como a tag está no topo, não funcionará, são milésimos de segundos, quando você pensar em clicar no X, já foi.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
     <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='/minha-outra-pagina'"/></noscript>
```

- No segundo caso eu não vou mostrar o código, minha resposta virou um tutorial, mais vou te dar a teórica, você vai usar o mesmo código inicial, mais com alguns diferenciais, o primeiro deles é que você não esconder ou mexer em nada, você vai apenas mudar a cor do `<body>`, inclua isso antes de `</head>`, dessa forma: `<noscript><style>.cnotjs{background-color:black:!important;}</style></noscript>`. No `<body>` vamos incluir a classe `cnotjs`, dessa forma: `<body class="cnotjs">`, deve ser o suficiente para ninguém ver nada, a não ser que você coloque um texto azul ou branco lá, ai o procedimento é outro.
  Por fim, você vai criar um alert dentro da tag `<noscript><!--- Aqui dentro ---></noscript>`, pode ser com uma div, você deve aplicar um Z-INDEX no alert para garantir que ele irá sobrepor os outros elementos e é isso, agora você pode dormir sossegado, sem se preocupar com essas coisas.