# O que é o Modelo de Maturidade de Richardson?

Tags: rest, http, semântica

Em uma pergunta que fiz sobre o HTTP foi [comentado sobre o Modelo de Maturidade de Richardson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361465/para-uma-busca-sem-resultados-a-resposta-http-deve-ser-404-204-ou-200-com-o-co/361684#comment722185_361465), pelo que entendi, o mesmo serve para definir o quão semântico seu servidor está em relação ao HTTP (se usa os verbos e retorna os status mais adequados, por exemplo)

Então uma aplicação que usa o verbo `POST` para deletar ou atualizar um recurso do servidor não está incorreto, mas seu nível de maturidade está baixo

- O que é esse modelo?
- Devemos tentar alcançar o nível mais alto de maturidade sempre?
- Ele está relacionado apenas a APIs REST?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**O que é esse modelo?**

É um modelo criado por [Leonard Richardson](https://www.crummy.com/writing/speaking/2008-QCon/act3.html) que quebra os elementos de uma API REST em 3 níveis. Sendo assim para você atingir o REST "real" você teria que alcançar o nível 3.

**Ele está relacionado apenas a APIs REST?**

Sim

**Devemos tentar alcançar o nível mais alto de maturidade sempre?**

Você deve fazer o que faz sentido para sua aplicação. Para isso vou dar uma breve explicação de cada nível.

***Nível 0: HTTP***

Você usa HTTP como forma de comunicação sem qualquer critério para a utilização de verbos, ou de rotas.

***Nível 1: HTTP + Recursos***

Sua API está exposta (roteada) seguindo o modelo de recursos. Como /users/ para listar todos os usuários e /users/123/ para obter um usuário especifico.

***Nível 2: HTTP + Recursos + Verbos***

Os verbos HTTP são usados de forma semântica na sua API. GET para leitura, POST para inserir, PUT para substituir um registro, DELETE para excluir...

***Nível 3: HTTP + Recursos + Verbos + HATEOAS***

A sua API deve retornar uma lista de recursos (rotas) com tudo o que é possível fazer a partir da chamada original.

```
GET /products/123 
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Orange"
  "links": [ 
    {"rel": "Suppliers", "href": "/suppliers/?product=123"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: O que significa esse _HATEOAS_? É uma sigla?

Comment: HATEOAS significa "Hypertext as the engine of application state" -- Veja este outro link no StackOverflow para maiores informações -- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49492/por-que-hateoas-%C3%A9-importante

Answer (score -1):

Os níveis de maturidade criados por Richardson definem os principios e restrições de implementação em uma API para que ela se torne RestFul.

> Como outros estilos arquitetônicos, o REST tem seus princípios e
> restrições orientadores. Esses princípios devem ser satisfeitos se uma
> interface de serviço precisa ser referida como RESTful.

A [Programmers](https://www.programmers.com.br/) tem um artigo sobre o tema e pode ser visto [aqui](https://www.programmers.com.br/blog/niveis-de-maturidade-de-uma-api-rest/).

Tem também o site da especificação que contém muitos detalhes a cerca de como implementar o modelo de maturidade e seus níveis com diversos exemplos. Pode ser visto [aqui](https://restfulapi.net/)