# Qual a melhor linguagem para RESTful ?

Tags: rest, independente-de-linguagem

Eu sou programador PHP, mas estou tendo dificuldade em achar formas uteis de fazer REST. E por isso estou pretendendo aprender uma segunda linguagem, já sei algumas, mas pode ser que exista uma melhor para fazer Rest.

Por favor me digam o porque da linguagem citada ser a melhor para fazer REST.

Comment: Você se refere algo do tipo a comunicação entre a interface gráfica com um servidor?

Comment: Da maneira como está, sua pergunta é muito ampla e é um convite a opiniões. Talvez valha a penar dar um pouco de foco a ela - por exemplo 'Quais linguagens/frameworks oferecem suporte extensivo a serviços RESTful?'

Comment: A linguagem não influencia nisto, o que talvez você queira seja um framework semi-pronto para o serviço, é triste ver como hoje os frameworks determinam a "qualidade" da linguagem para muitos. Desculpe a sinceridade, mas se eu fosse você eu desconsideraria qualquer resposta que indicar uma linguagem de programação.

Comment: Amigos, eu quero FATOS, estamos trabalhando com teologia ou exatas? A mais rápida, a melhor, com melhores conteúdos, com melhores apoio, a mais fácil, a mais usada. Números, meus colegas. É claro que aceito o que está inovando, mas tem que me dizer o porquê. Eu não quero teorias, eu quero números, 99 é maior que 98, então eu quero saber porque é 99 . É tão difícil assim vocês responderem fatos? Não quero discussões, não quero saber suas opiniões pessoais, quero o que o mercado está usando e está funcionando. Desculpem a sinceridade, mas eu sou muito obsessivo naquilo que procuro.

Comment: @AsuraKhan eu não dei teoria alguma, fiquei confuso com seu comentário. Eu só quis ressaltar que a linguagem pouco difere, o que você talvez deva se basear é qual o melhor framework e outra coisa, *opiniões pessoais* não podem ser consideradas aqui na comunidade como respostas. Quando eu disse *'é triste ver como hoje os frameworks determinam a "qualidade" da linguagem'* não me referia a você necessariamente, eu só coloquei aquele comentário por causa das possíveis respostas que poderiam aparecer.

Comment: E eu só queria saber se tem um melhor. Porque C++ tem as engine, photoshops da vida e etc. Java tem o android e sistemas móveis. Php tem a web inteira ou boa parte dela. Rest tem que ter, mas já que não tem então vou usar com a linguagem que eu sei. Eu particularmente não uso nenhum framework, mas a empresa cobra então fazer o que.

Comment: O c++ não tem o "Photoshop" e o Java não tem o "android", são tecnologias escritas ou que suportam as respectivas  linguagens, pelo seu comentário realmente a melhor dúvida seria: *qual a melhor API ou framework para tal tarefa?* Pois o interesse é em uma tecnologia específica. Acredito que qualquer uma das sugestões abaixo seja boa e mesmo que exista uma melhor, deve ser por pouca coisa. Algo que eu acredito ajudar a escolher uma API ou framework seria ver se a documentação é completa e fácil de entender.

Comment: Sobre usar ou não framework, vai do seu entendimento de REST, se você tem um conhecimento aprofundado nisto, realmente um framework não seria obrigatório, mas se está iniciando ou quer facilitar o trabalho um framework pode lhe auxiliar, para entender REST você terá que aprender o básico do HTTP, sobre "verbos" principalmente, mas garanto que o tempo de aprendizagem pode ser longo, pois em alguns casos será necessário aprender sobre transmissão de dados, geralmente usamos apenas ascii ou binário puros, mas há casos que deve haver codificação e autenticação por token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe uma linguagem que seja a melhor para REST de forma tão direta assim.

Vou deixa uma recomendação, Python !

Existe muitas ferramentas Interessantes para desenvolver API RESTFULL em python entre elas Web2py,Django

**Web2py**

[Doc REST+web2py](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Restful-Web-Services)

**Exemplo:**

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    response.view = 'generic.'+request.extension
    def GET(*args,**vars):
        patterns = [
            "/friends[person]",
            "/friend/{person.name.startswith}",
            "/friend/{person.name}/:field",
            "/friend/{person.name}/pets[pet.owner]",
            "/friend/{person.name}/pet[pet.owner]/{pet.name}",
            "/friend/{person.name}/pet[pet.owner]/{pet.name}/:field"
            ]
        parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns,args,vars)
        if parser.status == 200:
            return dict(content=parser.response)
        else:
            raise HTTP(parser.status,parser.error)
    def POST(table_name,**vars):
        if table_name == 'person':
            return db.person.validate_and_insert(**vars)
        elif table_name == 'pet':
            return db.pet.validate_and_insert(**vars)
        else:
            raise HTTP(400)
    return locals()
```

A novatec acabou de lançar um livro sobre REST com Django, [Link do livro](http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/django/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tópicos:**

- Conheça uma abordagem descomplicada para iniciar um novo projeto Django.
- Separe aplicações reutilizáveis em serviços menores que se comuniquem uns com os outros.
- Crie um site estático usando prototipação rápida como uma estrutura para sites e aplicações.
- Crie uma API REST com o django-rest-framework.
- Aprenda a usar o Django com o framework MVC Backbone.js.
- Crie uma aplicação web single-page usando a sua API REST.
- Integre recursos de tempo real com WebSockets e a biblioteca de rede Tornado.
- Utilize os exemplos orientados a códigos do livro em seus próprios projetos.

Answer (score 2):

REST é um estilo de arquitetura, e RESTfull é um serviço web que utiliza esse paradigma. Como você conhece PHP, dá uma verificada no SLIM e no SILEX que trata-se de dois micro-framework's que facilitam a utilização de RESTful. Mas não existe uma linguagem que seja "melhor" para RESTfull.

Comment: Me explique melhor essa diferença que se pudesse postar links aqui eu te mostraria uns 20 gringos dizendo que REST e RESTfull é a mesma coisa. Claro que eu só pesquisei em relação a linguagem que eu sei, isto é PHP.

Comment: Talvez esclareça: http://www.rodrigocalado.com.br/o-que-e-rest-um-resumo-do-assunto-caracteristicas-conceitos-vantagens-e-desvantagens-prefiro-dizer-que-e-uma-rapida-introducao-ao-assunto/ e este http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful. Basicamente REST é um paradigma arquitetônico e o RESTful é um serviço web que usufrui deste paradigma utilizando os verbos PUT, POST, GET e DELETE.