# Duvidas no web service

Tags: android, web-service, firebird

pessoal achei o seguinte tutorial de webservice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J87qN3B-dI

vendo o tutorial fiquei meio confuso a respeito.

1- o web service deve ser feito a parte do aplicativo android?

por exemplo eu crio um web service coloco esse web service no servidor e depois crio o aplicativo pelo android studio e faço a conexão com o web service?

2 - devo criar o web service pelo eclipse?

3 - nesse tutorial ele utiliza o mysql, mas eu preciso utilizar o firebird, neste caso devo colocar o banco.fdb em algum lugar no tomcat ou o banco sera acessado da mesmo forma pelo localhost igual no tutorial?

4 - tenho um sistema desktop em delphi, se eu fazer o web service em java pode ocorrer algum conflito?

eu não sei nada sobre web service estou os ultimo 3 dias pesquisando muito sobre, então agradeço todas as informações que puderem compartilhar comigo.

agradeço desde já

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Sim o *Webservice* é totalmente a parte do APP, resumindo o *webservice* é um "site" que é usado apenas para a transmissão de dados via HTTP de forma estruturada, por exemplo Json ou XML ao invés de HTML, sabendo isso então o seu APP vai acessar esse site sem precisar do navegador web e assim será a comunicação, tanto envio de *POST/PUT* quanto pegar dados como *GET*. Podemos usar REST ou SOAP, que nada mais que são dois formatos diferentes, no caso é provável que você prefira o REST, leia sobre ele em:

   - [O que é REST e RESTful?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/3635)
2. Pra criar o webservice não precisa de Eclipse, ele na verdade não cria nada ele é só uma IDE pra facilitar, no webservice você não expõe o banco de dados diretamente, pois isto seria uma baita brecha de segurança já que os APPs precisariam ter os dados de autenticação do banco de dados.

   Em base o APP faz uma requisição HTTP para uma página que devolve os dados de forma estruturada, como Json ou XML.

   Procurei várias imagens, mas acho que esta resume melhor:

   [image: web service]

   Veja que o **Client** é aonde estão computadores, celulares, tablets e outra "estação" (ou servidores, até mesmo outros sites podem requisitar um webservice), isto quer dizer que o webservice atende a vários locais. Serviço de Web seria a tradução, quer dizer que ele serve aos clientes dados via Web ou seja fora do APP, as aplicações apenas requisitam estes dados ou enviam novos dados e as vezes mantem uma cópia local pra acaso esteja offline ou otimizar.

   O webservice pode ser escrito de várias maneiras totalmente independente de IDE como disse antes, claro que usamos as IDEs pra facilitar, segue alguns exemplos de tecnologia pra usar no webservice + framework pra facilitar o desenvolvimento:

   - Se o seu servidor é PHP:

     - https://lumen.laravel.com
     - http://www.slimframework.com
     - http://silex.sensiolabs.org
   - Se usa .NET

     - http://www.asp.net/web-api
   - Python:

     - http://flask.pocoo.org
     - https://www.djangoproject.com

No caso a conexão com o banco ficará a cargo do **"server-side"**, neste caso do PHP, ASP.NET ou Python (usando framework ou não).

### Aplicativo

Se o App (aplicativo) for para Android pode usar o ADT ou o Eclipse mesmo pra desenvolver, pra acessar um webservice você deve fazer uma requisição HTTP (sendo android geralmente é java, fonte do exemplo http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/).

**Pegando dados (GET)**

```
String url = "http://[webservice].com";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("GET");

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Código de resposta: " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

//Pega a resposta
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}

in.close();

//Mostra a resposta no console
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

**Enviando dados (POST)**

```
String url = "http://[webservice].com/create";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//envia via POST
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

//Dados POST
String urlParameters = "arg2=foo&arg2=baz";

//Cria o POST
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Código de resposta: " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}

in.close();

//Mostra a resposta no console
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: as vezes eu fico meio sem saber o que fazer, por eu utilizar o android studio e a maioria dos tutoriais usarem eclipse, e as vezes os autores do tutorial usam alguns recursos do eclipse que eu não consigo achar no android studio, mas deu pra entender web service pelo seu post

Comment: @Tahatsu Entenda assim, o Eclipse não faz nada além de facilitar, ele será bom pra desenvolver o seu aplicativo, agora se no servidor/site for usar PHP por exemplo até o "bloco de notas" serve, você pode usar PHP no Eclipse também, mas será um projeto totalmente separado do projeto do App, o eclipse é só pra desenvolver/criar as coisas, quando estiverem em produção o eclipse não terá ligação alguma.

Comment: @Tahatsu outra coisa, geralmente os tutoriais usam Eclipse porque existem servidores http que usam java também, ou seja o cara cria um app android e esse usa java e cria um site java, como o eclipse é uma ferramenta pra facilitar parece que tanto o webservice quanto o app estão no mesmo lugar, mas são projetos diferentes esses tutorais apenas ensinaram a escrever usando o eclipse pra faciltiar mesmo.

Comment: então, esta era uma das minhas duvidas, eu achei que eram o mesmo projeto por isto toda esta confusão da minha parte kkkkkkk

Comment: @Tahatsu é justamente porque a maioria das pessoas, não só você, acham que as IDEs é que criam as coisas, mas é normal fazer esse tipo de confusão =) --- agora é só escolher a linguagem pro "site" e construir o webservice, eu geralmente uso eclipse pra criar os apps para android e pro PHP (linguagem que uso nos sites) eu uso notepad++ ou sublimetext

Comment: e outro ponto que esta criando uma certa confusão, é que o video tutorial que achei acho que esta utilizando o tal do SOAP e vocês me explicando o REST, então, meio que comecei a ficar mais confuso e só agora percebi que era SOAP, mas, o ideal é utilizar o REST?

Comment: @Tahatsu a escolha entre SOAP e REST é sua, no entanto eu pessoalmente acho REST muito mais simples, já que ele usa o proprio HTTP pra receber e enviar instruções ou dados.

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado pela atenção, agora vou tentar fazer meu aplicativo, obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 2):

1 - O web service é a parte do aplicativo Android ou de qualquer outro aplicativo que utilize esse serviço.

2 - Você pode criar pelo Eclipse, PHP, Python ou o que for mais fácil ou conveniente pra você.

3 - O WebService acessa o banco MYSQL, FIREBIRD, ORACLE ou qualquer outro banco via IP. Portanto seu banco pode esta na mesma maquina que esta o WEBSERVICE ou outra maquina na rede.

4 - O WebService responde a todas as requisições que chegarem independentemente de quem tenha solicitado, a não ser que seja programado para não faze-lo.

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/

Comment: estou usando o android studio no caso, em uma parte no tutorial que mandei o autor(utilizando eclipse) clica na classe java e cria uma webservice, devo fazer isto no android studio? ou utilizar extends Service funciona?

Comment: Acho que esse link que postei mais o comentário do Guilherme pode responder todas as suas questões e ajuda-lo a fazer um WebService funcional. Boa sorte.

Comment: #Taha,  vc não está confundido WebService com IntentService? São coisas totalmente diferentes...

Comment: como eu disse, estou muito confuso com essa parte de services

Comment: @Tahatsu sabe o que é HTTP?

Comment: é o protocolo de transferecia de informações, certo?.

Comment: @Tahatsu quando abre um site no navegador isso é via HTTP, então o webservice é um **site** só que com formato de dados estruturados, por exemplo Json ou XML ao invés de HTML, sabendo isso então o seu APP vai acessar esse site sem precisar do navegador web e assim será a comunicação, tanto envio de POST/PUT quanto pegar dados como GET.

Comment: estou lendo o seu post, esta dando para entender bem