# Como criar webservice utilizando PHP e REST?

Tags: php, web-service, rest

tenho pesquisado bastante sobre webservices ultimamente e gostaria da ajuda de vocês para saber como eu posso construir um webservice utilizando REST e PHP.
Escolhi PHP porque estou mais familiarizado com a linguagem, e o REST porque durante as minhas pesquisas vi que era o padrão mais utilizado atualmente e mais simples de se fazer. 
Antes de mais nada, já vi esse link sobre webservice que é bastante informativo por sinal: [Duvidas no web service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129473/duvidas-no-web-service) , mas que não sanou completamente minha dúvida. Minha dúvida na verdade é o que eu preciso fazer para meu projeto ser considerado um webservice?
Por exemplo, criei uma plataforma em PHP que faz as consultas no banco de dados e mostra esses dados na tela (em uma página php/html) para o usuário dependendo da requisição que ele faz. Isso é considerado um webservice? O que diferencia isso de um webservice e o que eu posso mudar nele para torná-lo um webservice? Como eu aplico o REST nisso?
Se possível, deixem tutoriais que ensinem como fazer ou trechos de código. Agradeço muito a colaboração de todos.

Answer (score 2):

É uma pergunta antiga mas vale a pena responder. Vamos por partes:

> Minha dúvida na verdade é o que eu preciso fazer para meu projeto ser
>   considerado um webservice?

Geralmente você utiliza webservices quando você quer permitir interoperabilidade (basicamente comunicação) entre diferentes plataformas (por exemplo, windows, linux, ios) escritos em diferentes linguagens. É claro que para permitir isso deve haver um formato de mensagem entendido por ambos (comumente json ou xml).

Basicamente você cria uma aplicação (com alguma linguagem do lado servidor, por exemplo, php, asp, ruby, python, etc.) mas em vez de retornar conteudo em html, css, e javascript, você retorna o conteudo, digamos "bruto", sem nenhuma formatação. Por exemplo, você define uma url (http://www.meusite.com/listarUsuarios), em vez de retornar uma pagina html, cheio de tags e estilos css, são retornados apenas os dados dos usuarios em texto plano, comumente json ou xml. Em json poderia ser algo assim: `[{nome: 'usuario 1', idade: 20}, {nome: 'usuario 2', idade: 30}]`. Em vez de retornar algo como `<html><body><table><tr><td>....`.

Então quando você está criando seu webservice você não estaria se preocupando com a apresentação (estilização), ou como isso vai ser apresentado para o usuario em um aplicativo. A aplicação cliente é que iria se preocupar em como os dados do webservice consumido seriam graficamente apresentados. É claro que o criador do webservice poderia muito bem criar uma aplicação cliente, em html e javascript, ou um app para android. (nativo ou hibrido).

> Por exemplo, criei uma plataforma em PHP que faz as consultas no banco
>   de dados e mostra esses dados na tela (em uma página php/html) para o
>   usuário dependendo da requisição que ele faz. Isso é considerado um
>   webservice?

Não. Pois entre outras coisas não há interoperabilidade (até é possivel com muito esforço). Se alguem quiser criar um aplicativo android nativo (escrito em java) para acessar essa url, e mostrar o conteudo, com elementos nativos do android (ListView, TextView, etc.) não seria tarefa facil receber um documento html (sem estrutura bem definida, ele teria que olhar) e procurar as informações relevantes (os dados retornados pela consulta sql no banco, sem nada de formatação html) no meio de varias tags html.

Você até poderia ter essa pagina que lista as informações em html, mas ela será uma aplicação consumindo o webservice que retorna apenas os dados tal qual foram retornados pela consulta sql.

> Como eu aplico o REST nisso? Se possível, deixem tutoriais que ensinem
>   como fazer ou trechos de código

No [imasters](https://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/aprenda-a-usar-o-restful-com-php-e-slim-framework/?trace=1519021197&source=single) há um bom tutorial mostrando como se constroi o webservice (aplicação do lado servidor).