# Pagamento ao usuário usando Paypal e Swift

Tags: swift

Estou tentando a dias encontrar um exemplo de código em swift necessário para executar um pagamento ao usuário.

O guia de desenvolvimento do PayPal não contém a sintaxe em swift e toda tentativa que fiz tentando traduzir de outras linguagens foi mal sucedida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o [repositório público do PayPal no github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) você não consegue fazer operação de `Pagamento(Payout)` diretamente pelo SDK iOS:

> The SDK supports two use cases for making payments - Single Payment
>   and Future Payments - and a third use case for obtaining information
>   about the customer - Profile Sharing.

Para fazer esse tipo de operação você terá que implementar seu código backend usando umas das API's do PayPal:

[C#](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/PayoutCreate.aspx.cs) | [JAVA](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/payouts/servlet/CreateBatchPayoutServlet.java) | [Node.js](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/payout/create.js) | [PHP](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payouts/CreateBatchPayout.php) | [Python](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payout/create.py) | [Ruby](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/blob/master/samples/payouts/create.rb)

e então se comunicar com seu backend pelo app, por exemplo, usando o padrão [API REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful)

---

Segue um exemplo de como usar a API em Ruby para fazer um payout:

```
require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
require 'securerandom'
require './runner.rb'

include PayPal::SDK::REST
include PayPal::SDK::Core::Logging

@payout = Payout.new({
                         :sender_batch_header => {
                             :sender_batch_id => SecureRandom.hex(8),
                             :email_subject => 'You have a Payout!'
                         },
                         :items => [
                             {
                                 :recipient_type => 'EMAIL',
                                 :amount => {
                                     :value => '12.34', # valor com até 2 casas decimais representada como string
                                     :currency => 'USD' # código da moeda de 3 letras
                                 },
                                 :note => 'Thanks for your patronage!', # observação para as notificações. A observação é fornecida pelo emissor do pagamento.
                                 :sender_item_id => '2014031400023', # um número de identificação específico do remetente, pode ser usado em um sistema de contabilidade para fins de rastreamento.
                                 :receiver => 'shirt-supplier-one@mail.com' # o recebedor do pagamento.
                             }
                         ]
                     })
begin
  @payout_batch = @payout.create
  logger.info "Created Payout with [#{@payout_batch.batch_header.payout_batch_id}]"
rescue ResourceNotFound => err
  logger.error @payout.error.inspect
end
```

**Lembrando que:** Para usar Pagamentos, você deve solicitar o acesso através de sua página da conta. Alternativamente, entre em contato com seu gerente de conta ou Suporte ao Cliente do PayPal. ***Você deve ter uma conta comercial do PayPal.***