# Chamada de funções distintas via Ajax com Jquery em PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte exemplo:

Meu arquivo **HTML** tem este trecho de código:

```
<script> 
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                    url : 'funcoes.php',//url para acessar o arquivo
                    data: {id : 10},//parametros para a funcao
                    type : 'post',//PROTOCOLO DE ENVIO PODE SER GET/POST
                    dataType : 'json',//TIPO DO RETORNO JSON/TEXTO 
                    success : function(data){//DATA É O VALOR RETORNADO
                        alert(data.valor);//VALOR INDICE DO ARRAY/JSON
                    },
        });
});
</script>
```

e tenho também um arquivo chamado **funcoes.php** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php
    function teste(){
      echo json_encode(array('valor' => $_POST['id']));
    }

    function teste2(){
      echo json_encode(array('valor' => $_POST['id']));
    }
?>
```

Oque eu gostaria de saber é: Como acessar a função teste1(ou teste2)?
Oque tenho que passar como "parâmetro" no meu arquivo HTML para que ele saiba qual destas duas funções desejo executar ?

Comment: Aconselho ler um pouco sobre [REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful)

Comment: Você pode passar como data, algo como: `data: {id : 10, acao: "algumaCoisaQueDefineQualFuncaoVaiSerAcessada"}`
E no backend usar um `switch case` para filtrar qual função deve ser acessada quando passado tal ação

Comment: Entendi sua ideia, irei tentar aplicar ela e volto com o resultado, agradeço também pela indicação de leitura sobre REST, dando uma lida de relance ja vi que tem várias coisas que se enquadram com minha necessidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria mesmo você utilizar **REST API** para conseguir acessar diretamente a função que deseja, recomendo dar uma lida sobre o assunto. Se houver a possibilidade também, seria interessante utilizar um **framework** PHP, caso seu projeto comporte esse tipo de recurso.

Agora se atendo a sua necessidade você poderia passar um parâmetro adicional em sua chamada ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'funcoes.php',
    data: {id : 10, acessar: 'teste'},
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
        alert(data['valor']);
    }
});
```

E no arquivo **funcoes.php** ficaria:

```
<?php
    function teste(){
      echo json_encode(array('valor' => $_POST['id']));
    }

    function teste2(){
      echo json_encode(array('valor' => $_POST['id']));
    }

    if($_POST['acessar'] == 'teste'){
        teste();
    } else if($_POST['acessar'] == 'teste2') {
        teste2();
    }
?>
```

Olhando para seu ambiente seria uma abordagem desse tipo.

Comment: Boa tarde Pedro Souza, muito obrigado pela resposta, a mesma se encaixa perfeitamente com a pergunta que fiz. Sobre utilizar REST, já estou fazendo leitura e vejo que realmente tem tudo haver com minha necessidade.

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha ajudado. Boa sorte ai!

Comment: Estou começando agora e as vezes fico apreensivo de perguntar algumas coisas, mas caso seja possível uma ultima ajuda eu agradeço, oque eu gostaria de saber é como jogar o resultado de:
"$.ajax({
    url : 'funcoes.php',
    data: {id : 10, acessar: 'teste'},
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
        alert(data.valor);
    }
});" em uma variavel javascript.

Comment: Não precisa ficar apreensivo, estamos todos aqui para aprender ou/e transmitir conhecimento. Editei a minha resposta colocando "alert(data['valor']);" na função success. Realmente eu não havia me atentado a isso, você no PHP respondeu com um array, logo a forma de acessar é data['valor'] e não data.valor que seria um objeto.