# Qual a diferença em usar ModelAndView e ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Me deparei com essas duas classe, achei a função delas bem iguais.
Quais são as diferenças entre elas e quando é o momento de usar uma específica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ResponseEntity:* significa representar toda a resposta HTTP. Você pode controlar qualquer coisa que aconteça: código de status, cabeçalhos e corpo.

> Trabalhando com microservice, ResponseEntity para enviar resposta
>   completa, com status, com cabeçalho e corpo.

*ModelAndView*: essa classe é utilizada para especificar a view que será renderizada e quais os dados ela utilizará para isso.

> ModelAndView padrão MVC.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Sobre a questão da usabilidade, o `ResponseEntity` é muito utilizado em arquiteturas voltadas a serviço (SOA), especificamente na construção de APIs [REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful), como elemento de resposta (response, daí o nome) para a chamada de determinado serviço.