# Como eu posso enviar uma variável PHP numa página para uma outra página Javascript usando Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá, pessoas, eu gostaria de saber como envio uma variável php para um outro documento javascript por meio do Ajax.

A variável PHP em questão é essa:

```
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($show));
```

Aqui ela me retorna o valor de uma string, porem vi que o Json tem uma função Json.parse, que converte tudo isso para objetos, assim, fica mais fácil manipular para fazer uma tabela, porém, eu quero fazer as coisas separadas, a página php recebe esses valores e a javascript manda para o html onde o usuário verá seu cadastro, se, houver um método mais fácil e seguro eu aceito também, de modo geral, enviar essa variável para uma página JS/Json e lá farei a tabela com as informações

Comment: Complemente sua pergunta com o código completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você esta fazendo parte dos conceitos utilizados em uma API REST. [Veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful)

Backend se encarrega de gerir e fornecer os dados em um formato prático como o json, a partir daí, a responsabilidade de exibir estes dados é da aplicação do Frontend ( ou outro backend em caso de microserviços).

Um exemplo com jQuery:

`var objetoJS = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonDoServidor)`

`jsonDoServidor` é o que foi gerado pelo seu `json_encode(simplexml_load_string($show));`

Nota: Isso deve ser trafegado para seu JS de alguma forma, seja via http comum (no estilo Rotas de API) ou até mesmo na renderização (não é a melhor pratica mais funciona).

Se for fazer via renderização, na hora que seu PHP gerar o HTML, você pode fazer algo embutindo PHP no JS. Exemplo:

```
index.html

<script> 
var jsonDoServidor = jQuery.parseJSON(
      <?php echo json_encode(simplexml_load_string($show)); ?>
)
console.log(jsonDoServidor)
</script>
```

Repare que, o seu PHP esta criando a jsonDoServidor dinamicamente para ser usada pelo JS.
Isso funciona, porém, talvez não seja a melhor prática.

Uma alternativa melhor, é você criar um arquivo/rota que retorne apenas o JSON e, através de uma chamada ajax, pegar este conteúdo e utilizá-lo.

```
$.get("/linkproJson").done(function(data){
  console.log(data)
  var jsonDoServidor = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
});
```

Seja la como você for fazer, com isso você os dados em um Obj pronto para utilização no JS.

Eu tentei explicar com base no que entendi, mas sua pergunta não foi tão direta.

Para ajudá-lo a ter ideias, veja o que eu tenho de forma similar a sua necessidade (Utilizo isso com o Laravel, então as tags PHP são simplificadas mas o conceito é o mesmo):

```
// Recebe o Json para a view
produtos = {!! $analises->produtos or $analisesProdutos !!} 

// Pega a tabela 
var tableRef = document.getElementById('analisesProdutos-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Cria as linhas na tabela com os dados que vieram do Servidor
produtos.forEach(function (item) {
    var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(item);
    newRow.innerHTML = `
    <td><a href="/analisesProdutos/${item.id_mlb}">${item.id_mlb}</a></td>
    <td>${item.seller_mlb}</td>
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td>${item.price}</td>
    <td>${item.sold_on_register}</td>
    <td id='${item.id_mlb}-sold_last'></td>
    <td></td>
    `
})
```