# Qual tipo de banco de dados usar e como não criar muitas activities?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio, android-fragment, tabela-banco-de-dados

Pretendo criar um aplicativo, que irá utilizar reconhecimento de código de barras, desse código de barra irá levar à uma tela sobre o medicamento, a parte do database não sei qual utilizar, pois nunca usei, a tela eu pretendo criar uma e reutilizar, mas, teria alguma forma mais simples?

Comment: Mais fácil que isso? Não. É isso mesmo. Banco de dados dentro do dispositivo, se você pretende ter disponibilidade online e estar sempre atual, não **precisa** (apesar de um cache ser recomendável por UX).

Comment: Pretendo conectar esse banco à internet, pois preciso adicionar os nomes, códigos de barra, e informações do objeto que devo sempre atualizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Qual tipo de banco de dados usar?**
>
> "desse código de barra irá levar à uma tela sobre o medicamento"

Recomendo criar uma [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful), por facilidade de edição dos dados, segurança, e evitar ocupar espaço desnecessário nos dispositívos dos usuários.

Para fazer a API você pode usar [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/), SlimPHP entre outros frameworks PHP, em um vps [LAMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-a-pilha-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-no-ubuntu-18-04-pt). Recomendo fazer autenticação para obter os dados da API.

Para obter os dados da API, use [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley)

Caso realmente queira armazenar no dispositivo, use o SQLite do android. Ex.: [Exemplo aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-crud-com-android-studio-e-sqlite/32815)

> **Como não criar muitas activities?**

Você pode usar [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=pt-br). Ex.: [Exemplo aqui](https://www.androidpro.com.br/blog/desenvolvimento-android/fragments/)

No geral, faça Activities ou Fragments que recebam parâmetros e busquem as informações na API.

Comment: É interessante sempre tentar postar algo significativo na resposta, deixando links como referência/material de aprofundamento. De toda sorte, creio que a [resposta da Júlia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353074/64969) complementa a sua a respeito dos fragmentos.

Comment: A parte do LAMP, eu não possuo linux uso o windows 7, existe outra forma como máquina virtual, etc?

Comment: @PedroHenrique No windows você pode usar [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html) ou [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Answer (score 1):

Quanto à tela você pode utilizar fragments. É possível criar uma activity com apenas um frameLayout como no exemplo abaixo:

```xml
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fgmContent"/>
```

Aí você pode manipular os fragments utilizando o FragmentManager e o FragmentTransaction.

```java
manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fgmContent, new SeuFragment());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```