# Criar/alterar entidades em lote

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estou lendo um livro de Angular 5 + Asp.NET Core 2.0 (apesar de eu estar usando Angular 7 e Asp.NET Core 2.1), e estou tentando fazer o sistema que esse livro ensina a fazer. É um sistema de Quiz, onde você pode criar seus quizzes, possuindo várias perguntas, cada pergunta possuindo várias respostas.

Já criei a web api para o CRUD básico para cada tipo de entidade: Quiz, Pergunta e Resposta.

Lembrando que cada Quiz possui perguntas, e cada pergunta possui respostas.

Seguindo o livro, para eu criar uma pergunta, o quiz já deve existir no banco de dados. O mesmo vale para as respostas: para criar uma, sua pergunta já deve estar criada.

Eu gostaria de fazer um ambiente onde o usuário pudesse inserir TODAS as informações do quiz, das perguntas e das respostas antes de enviar os dados para o servidor. Ou seja, gostaria que existisse a possibilidade de criar o quiz, as perguntas e as respostas no lado do cliente e, quando o usuário estiver pronto, salvar tudo o que tem pra salvar de uma só vez.

Faz sentido fazer dessa forma? É viável?
Se sim, eu devo criar um loops para enviar as perguntas e as respostas para o servidor? Ou devo enviar tudo em um único objeto e tratar os dados do lado do servidor?

Tentei fazer um loop no Angular, mas acho que o javascript não se dá muito bem com callbacks de pedidos assíncronos dentro de loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode sim mandar tudo em um objeto apenas.

Há muita discussão sobre isso quando se está criando [APIs RESTFul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful). Pois se tem por convenção que cada objeto deve ter seu próprio Controlador e que os métodos POST recebam apenas um objeto.

Mas isso vai sempre de acordo com as necessidades do programador/software.

Se for enviar tudo de uma vez, você pode montar e enviar o JSON desta forma por exemplo:

```
var Quiz = {
   nome: "Quiz 01",
   perguntas: [
      {
         nome: "Pergunta01",
         respostas: [
            {
               nome: "resposta A"
            },
            {
               nome: "resposta B"
            }
          ]
      },
      {
         nome: "Pergunta 02",
         respostas: [
            {
               nome: "resposta A"
            },
            {
               nome: "resposta B"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Entendo. Nesse caso então o controlador do quiz receberia um objeto Quiz contendo todas as perguntas e respostas e, após incluir o quiz no BD, chamaria o controlador de perguntas (que por consequência chamaria o controlador de respostas)?

Comment: Neste caso recomendo você tratar cada persistência de forma separada.
Vai depender do ORM que você estiver trabalhando também... Entity, Nhibernate, Dapper.

No Entity se não me engano você conseguiria salvar tudo de uma vez só, apenas adicionando o objeto Quiz ao contexto e salvando as mudanças.

Comment: Estou usando o Entity Framework, mas vou tratar de forma separada mesmo. Em futuros projetos, vou manter sua resposta em mente.