# Uma requisição de dados de outro dado deve responder com 404 ou um array vazio?

Tags: api, rest, http, restful

Estou trabalhando com uma API a qual possui a seguinte rota `users/:id/documents`.

Esta rota deverá retornar uma lista de documentos de um usuário especifico.

Por exemplo:

a rota `users/:id/documents` deverá retornar todos os documentos do usuário com `id 1`.

caso ele não possua nenhum documento, a rota retornará um array vazio com status 200, porem caso a requisição seja feita com um `id` de usuário inexistente devo retornar 404 ou um array vazio da mesma forma?

Comment: Como to sem tempo pra dar uma resposta mais digna, vai aqui mesmo: retorna 404, um array vazio é uma possibilidade de retorno, o id não existir, não.

Comment: Acho que no final essa pergunta vai acabar "baseada em opiniões". Esse é um tema bem controverso. Há quem ache que retornar 404 é uma brecha de segurança, uma vez que há a indicação se o user existe ou não. Há quem ache que deve retornar mesmo 404, pq nenhum user será encontrado. E haverá quem ache que deve retornar 400 (bad request) ou até mesmo algum 5xx.

Comment: @tvdias  400 (bad request) nunca seria usado para isto, a não ser que a pessoa não saiba o que esta fazendo, não tem haver com "problema" do servidor, tem haver com problema vindo do lado cliente: [*The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)*](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, como  disse, há quem defenda que é um erro do usuário, já que se fizer um GET a `users/:id` retornaria um 404.

Comment: @tvdias Uma coisa é a ID não existir, outra é escrever uma ID em "formato invalido", se ficar relativizando vai começar a criar "mitos"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento por isso mesmo que as resposta são baseadas em opiniões. Da mesma forma como vc tem as suas, outras pessoas têm outras. E mesmo a resposta é toda assim `Não gosto do 404 porque é`, `porque não usar o 204 No Content?`, etc...

Comment: Leitura recomendada sobre a "opinatividade" ou não do assunto: [Subjetivo bom, subjetivo ruim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/70)

Comment: @tvdias eu não to falando da pergunta e da resposta, eu só falei de algo que você afirmou que não era e que se alguém um dia lhe disse pra você fazer/usar (mesmo que você discordasse da pessoa) é pq não sabia o que estava fazendo. Sobre o mérito da pergunta, eu **não** entrei nisso em nenhum momento.

Comment: id em um formato invalido estou retornando 400 mesmo, minha duvida é somente caso o id não existir, já que se trata de uma requisição dos documentos e o id é do usuario, porem ao mesmo tempo são os documentos deste usuário.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, por favor leia novamente o meu comentário. E como disse, da mesma forma como vc tem a *sua* opinião, outras pessoas podem discordar. Eu tenho a *minha* opinião e por achar que seria "mais uma dentre muitas", nem a expus.

Comment: @tvdias não tem opinião alguma, você disse que alguém afirmou uma coisa, mas seja lá quem afirmou isso ai provavelmente não sabia o que estava fazendo, mesmo que você tenha acreditado na conversa dessa pessoa ou não. Como eu disse, é nessa forma de "achismo" (não seu, mas dessa suposta pessoa que você citou) que nascem os "mitos" (erros), são pessoas fazendo coisa errada e só porque "funciona" começam a afirmar que é o certo ou que é uma forma de fazer, sendo na verdade é tudo um equívoco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende da semântica que quer dar. E [**há controvérsias**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11746894/221800) quanto a isso. Algumas pessoas afirmam categoricamente uma coisa, outras são mais ponderadas. Então não considere esta uma resposta que diz o que você deve fazer, estou colocando algumas possibilidades para você decidir.

## Algumas ponderações

Pense na API sem ser web, se tivesse métodos no mesmo executável, o que você retornaria? Seria um *array* vazio? Ou seria uma exceção? O 404 nesse caso é como a exceção.

Há quem goste de lançar exceção pra todo lado e então o 404 faria até sentido. Eu acho que deve informar que algo errado aconteceu de outra forma. Pra mim exceções só devem ocorrer se algo excepcional foi encontrado. Se é algo normal acontecer não deveria gerar exceção. E ter zero itens é algo normal de acontecer, não é? Talvez não o que a pessoa queria, mas é uma resposta normal?

Tem tecnologia que gosta das exceções para tudo.

Não gosto do 404 porque é a mesma resposta que teria se você colocar um URL e ele não existir por completo, então você está usando o mesmo código para duas coisas diferentes. Eu concordaria até com um outro 400, mas nenhum me parece apropriado. Se for outro pelo menos indica outra coisa. Se você achar outro que fica bom então deveria usá-lo.

Por que não usar o [`204 No Content`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)? Parece mais apropriado, pelo menos não mistura as coisas. E quem sabe teria o *array* vazio. Assim você tem uma resposta normal, que deu certo, mas um indicativo claro que o dado não deve ser usado. Não estou dizendo que é uma boa usar assim, mas é melhor que 404, **pra mim**. Pelo menos diz que a requisição foi bem sucedida, mas não tem dados válidos.

Algumas pessoas gostam até de 200 e não indicar no código que não há dados, isso deve ser verificado na mensagem resultante internamente. Isso é o adequado se você quer deixar o código HTTP só para indicar o que aconteceu com o transporte e sua segunda hipótese. Abre mão do [REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/101).

Lendo a [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-1.3) dá uma indicação que essa é uma tecnologia que gosta das exceções. Lá na página 8 tem um trecho que ela trata os dados como o recurso que você está querendo acessar. Então será que o 404 não é o meio mais tecnicamente correto para esse caso? Veja:

> A network data object or service that can be identified by a URI, as defined in section 3.2. Resources may be available in multiple representations (e.g. multiple languages, data formats, size, and resolutions) or vary in other ways.

## Conclusão

Eu não gosto muito do uso de código HTTP para dar semântica do sistema, mas o povo que ama REST resolveu adotar assim, não sou eu que vou dizer o que é bom para você.

Então não dá para decidir por você, ambos funcionam se você fizer certo e não funcionam se fizer errado. O mais importante é ser consistente.

Uma coisa que pode te ajudar é perguntar para os usuários o que eles costumam usar com outras APIs, pode ser que isso indique a consistência, mas desconfie, nem sempre o usuário tem razão, muitas vezes ele é a pessoa que menos entende do assunto.

Comment: `o povo que ama REST resolveu adotar assim` pois é, acho que o REST ajudou bastante em muita coisa, mas tem suas deficiências e depois te obrigam a fazer uma coisa que não faz o menor sentido `pq no REST é assim`.

Comment: @tvdias REST é feito como cada um gosta e não tem formato padrão algum, e provavelmente o AR não falou que o REST foi o problema, o problema é o  "povo que ama" e começaram a inventar "regras" e "mitos". Ninguém te obriga a nada (a não ser que seja o seu gerente de projeto ou patrão), só faz isso se não sabe o que esta fazendo ou esta seguindo "receita de bolo".

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante a esclarecer minha duvida.