# Método POST não funciona corretamente Node.js e express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, express.js

boa noite, por via de testes eu criei uma pequena API para entender seu funcionamento, no entanto ao executar o método POST me deparei que ela só me retorna as chaves vazias:

```
[
{}
]
```

O correto seria me devolver assim: (quando executo o GET após o POST)

```
  [
    {
        "name": "Leandro",
        "id": "1"
    }
  ]
```

Achei que poderia ser meu codigo mas eu peguei o da aula pra testar e obtive o mesmo resultado, tentei dar permissão a mais nas manipulações dos arquivos mas não resolveu, se alguém souber ou que já passou por isso toda ajuda é bem vinda, lembrando que sou iniciante em Node.js:

Segue meu código:

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const usersRoute = require('./routes/usersRoute')
const port = 3000

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

usersRoute(app)

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Olá mundo!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express rodando na porta ${port}`))
```

usersRoute.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { join } = require('path')

const filePath = join(__dirname, 'users.json');

const getUsers = () => {
    const data = fs.existsSync(filePath)
        ? fs.readFileSync(filePath)
        : []

    try {
        return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
        return [];      
    }
};

const saveUser = (users) => fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(users, null, '\t'));

const userRouter = (app) => {

    app.route('/users/:id?')
        .get((req, res) => {
            const users = getUsers()
            res.send({ users })
        })
        .post((req, res) => {
            const users = getUsers()

            users.push(req.body)
            saveUser(users)

            res.status(201).send('OK')
        })
        .put((req, res) => {
            const users = getUsers()
            saveUser(users.map(user => {
                if (user.id === req.params.id) {
                    return {
                        ...user,
                        ...req.body
                    }
                }

                return user
            }))

            res.status(200).send('OK')
        })
        .delete((req, res) => {
            const users = getUsers()
            saveUser(users.filter(user => user.id !== req.params.id))

            res.status(200).send('OK')
        })
}

module.exports = userRouter
```

e o metodo POST que executo com o PostMan:

```
localhost:3000/users?name=Lucas&id=1
```

Comment: `localhost:3000/users?name=Lucas&id=1` se esta passando assim já tem problemas não é assim que passa

Comment: Eu faço o POST e depois executo o GET para ver o retorno, a minha dúvida é por que o POST não insere os dados?

Comment: Você está criando suas próprias abstrações de como deveria funcionar uma api, seu código não se parece com uma api tradicional desenvolvida em express. Não tem como validar opinar em sua arquitetura.

Comment: esse exemplo de codigo peguei daqui https://github.com/hmschreiner/node-express, estou iniciando Node.js, se tiver alguma referencia pra me passar com exemplos.

Comment: Você está passando errado por isso não tem o resultado que espera ... essa API o arquivo JSON é editado localmente.

Comment: Veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful) para entender melhor como funcionam APIs REST.