# Como funciona e como é adicionado um sistema de pagamentos no site?

Tags: pagamento-online

Nunca entendi como nestes sites (e-commerce) as compras são realizadas entre o usuário e o sistema de pagamento e muitos deles os sistemas de pagamentos se diferenciam o que dá a entender que há vários tipos de sistemas de pagamentos no mercado.

Eu possuo um site online e quero começar a vender alguns projetos, mas não sei por onde começar e pior que eu não sei como funciona ou como adicionar um sistema de pagamentos no meu site.

Tenho outras dúvidas relacionadas:

**É algum tipo de API de um banco ou uma empresa que é adicionado no site?**

**Ou para ser mais preciso eu mesmo poderia criar um sistema de pagamento no meu site do zero?**

**Estes tipos de sistemas de pagamentos usam linguagens do lado do servidor como PHP?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"É algum tipo de API de um banco ou uma empresa que é adicionado no site?"***
Sim é o que normalmente se faz, alguns exemplos são "PagSeguro", "MercadoPago" e "PayPal", que nesse caso são *gateways*, ou seja, não são os próprios bancos ou administradoras de cartão, mas empresas que fazem "a ponte" entre a sua aplicação e os bancos/administradoras.

***Ou para ser mais preciso eu mesmo poderia criar um sistema de pagamento no meu site do zero?***
Não é recomendado, porque tem que implementar muitas coisas de segurança em se tratando de dados sensíveis, como dados bancários e de cartão de crédito. É melhor contar com serviços que já fornecem várias opições de pagamaneto prontas, como boleto, TED/PIX, débito em conta ou cartão de crédito, e mesmo que queria fazer seu próprio sistema, vai ter de implementar cada um deles individualmente.

***Estes tipos de sistemas de pagamentos usam linguagens do lado do servidor como PHP?***
Sim tem que ser do lado servidor, logo pode ser `PHP` ou outra linguagem que rode do lado servidor como `Javascript (Node)`, `.NET` ou  `Java`, mas se for usar um serviço que que já existe, a linguagem pouco importa, pois se é uma API, e o importante é poder fazer chamadas respeitando o protocoloco de comunicação da API, como  `HTTP`/`HTTPS`, que pode ser implementada em qualquer linguagem que dê suporte a esses protocolos e demais requisitos, como `REST` ou `SOAP` (legado).

Aqui no site tem boas perguntas para te ajudar sobre alguns *gateways* de pagamento conhecidos do mercado e sobre o padrão `REST`:

[PagSeguro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pag%20seguro)
[MercadoPago](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mercadopago)
[Paypal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20paypal)
[Gateway de pagamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gateway%20pagamento)
[O que é REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful)